# Rails Asset Pipeline How Does //= require jquery work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

`//= require jquery`

How is the jquery library being loaded in with this?

I do not have jquery files anywhere in the project to be loaded.

What magical place are they loaded from?

Same goes for `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` I put this line in so that bootstrap was loaded correctly.

I have the gem but what magic is done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those files got loaded because you have the `gem 'jquery-rails'` and the `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'`

they hold the js, css, and images  files in the assets directory inside there gem

what the Rails Asset Pipeline does is look at the **assets** and **vendor** directories to compile the files

I hope that this explanation works

you can see the assets for [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets) and [jQuery](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts) here

Comment: So when are the assets for `query-rails` and `bootstrap-sass` added into the Asset Pipeline? Part of the Asset Pipeline is to look at all the gems and see if they have assets?

Comment: I want to say on startup

Comment: So the `require` maybe looks at assets under app/assets and if it isn't there looks through the gems?